# What's the difference between InvokeAsync and BeginInvoke for WPF Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, async-await

I noticed in .NET 4.5 that the [WPF Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907.aspx) had gotten a new set of methods to execute stuff on the Dispatcher's thread called [InvokeAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199387.aspx). Before, .NET 4.5 we had [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604730%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which handled this syncronously and asynchronously respectively.

Besides the naming and the slightly different overloads available, are there any major differences between the `BeginInvoke` and the `InvokeAsync` methods?

Oh, and I already checked, both can be `await`ed:

```
private async Task RunStuffOnUiThread(Action action)
{
    // both of these works fine
    await dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
    await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(action);
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are no differences as the `BeginInvoke` method calls a private `LegacyBeginInvokeImpl` method which itslef calls the private method `InvokeAsyncImpl` (the method used by `InvokeAsync`). So it's basically the same thing. It seems like it's a simple refactoring, however it's strange the `BeginInvoke` methods weren't flagged as obsolete.

**BeginInvoke :**

```
public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method)
{
    return this.LegacyBeginInvokeImpl(priority, method, null, 0);
}

private DispatcherOperation LegacyBeginInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)
{
    Dispatcher.ValidatePriority(priority, "priority");
    if (method == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
    }
    DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperation = new DispatcherOperation(this, method, priority, args, numArgs);
    this.InvokeAsyncImpl(dispatcherOperation, CancellationToken.None);
    return dispatcherOperation;
}
```

**InvokeAsync :**

```
public DispatcherOperation InvokeAsync(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority)
{
    return this.InvokeAsync(callback, priority, CancellationToken.None);
}

public DispatcherOperation InvokeAsync(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (callback == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
    }
    Dispatcher.ValidatePriority(priority, "priority");
    DispatcherOperation dispatcherOperation = new DispatcherOperation(this, priority, callback);
    this.InvokeAsyncImpl(dispatcherOperation, cancellationToken);
    return dispatcherOperation;
}
```

Comment: Currently I'm getting unhandled exceptions working as expected using BeginInvoke (triggering both DispatcherUnhandledException on the dispatcher and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException), but unhandled exceptions on InvokeAsync are being silently swallowed. Continuing the task from InvokeAsync with something to trap exceptions seems to be a valid work around.

Comment: `BeginInvoke` is patterned after the ["Asynchronous Programming Model"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) in .NET that uses `BeginSomething` and `EndSomething` methods for asynchronous operations. Presumably this is why it wasn't designated deprecated or obsolete. Except that the `Begin`/`End` convention is for using `IAsyncResult`, and `BeginInvoke` doesn't, nor is there any `EndInvoke`, so it was kind of superfluous in the first place.

Comment: The DispatcherOpartion returned from the constructor has a memberfield useAsyncSematics which is set based on the constructor used. This causes a difference in the exception handling when using async and await. See my answer.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. The exception handling is different in the two cases. See @Wouter's answer.

Answer (score 70):

The exception handling is different.

You may want to check the following:

```
private async void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;
    try
    {
        await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(Throw));
    }
    catch
    {
        // The exception is not handled here but in the unhandled exception handler.
        MessageBox.Show("Catched BeginInvoke.");
    }

    try
    {
       await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((Action)Throw);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Catched InvokeAsync.");
    }
}

private void OnUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Catched UnhandledException");
}

private void Throw()
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.  The fact that `BeginInvoke` brings down the app on an unhandled exception vs. `InvokeAsync` flowing the exception back through the returned awaitable is a HUGE difference.

Comment: @jam40jeff Good point. For those migrating from BeginInvoke to InvokeAsync: imagine a huge legacy application with loads of calls to BeginInvoke. If that is refactored to use InvokeAsync, then an unhandled exception will bubble up from the point of the exception, bringing down the calling thread. On the other hand, BeginInvoke would pass that exception into the main application handler, which is caught and wouldn't bring the application down. Either way, they are not drop-in replacements for each other, and when switching from one to another, test the differences in behavior.

Comment: You state that exception handling is different and give a code example. But you never explicitly state _how_ the exception handling is different. The quality of your answer would improve if you add that.

Comment: @JHBonarius See the comment in the first exception handler.

Answer (score 17):

There is a difference in method signature:

```
BeginInvoke(Delegate, Object[])
InvokeAsync(Action)
```

For `BeginInvoke()` compiler creates array `Object[]` implicitly while for `InvokeAsync()` such array is not needed:

```
IL_0001:  ldarg.0
IL_0002:  call       instance class [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject::get_Dispatcher()
IL_0007:  ldarg.1
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0
IL_0009:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Object
IL_000e:  callvirt   instance class [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::BeginInvoke(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate, object[])


IL_0014:  ldarg.0
IL_0015:  call       instance class [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject::get_Dispatcher()
IL_001a:  ldarg.1
IL_001b:  callvirt   instance class [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation [WindowsBase]System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher::InvokeAsync(class [mscorlib]System.Action)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, one difference I've noticed is that InvokeAsync has a generic overload that returns a DispatcherOperation as a return value and accepts a Func as its delegate input parameter.  Thus, you can retrieve the result of the operation via InvokeAsync in a type-safe way analogous to how you can await the result of a Task.