# Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() not running asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task, dispatcher

Here's a simplified version of what I want to do:

onClick a `button`, a `aNewMethod()` would run asynchronously to keep UI responsive. That's it!

I've read some answers and here's what i could come up with :

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(() => aNewMethod());
        await task;
    }

    private void aNewMethod()
    {
        if (progress.Value == 0)
        {
            //Heavy work
            for (int i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) { }
            progress.Value = 100;
        }
    }
```

As you may have thought, this throws a `System.InvalidOperationException` at `if(progress.Value== 0)` saying :

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

after some Googling, I've read that I need a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` method to update/use UI controls, so I did this :

```
    private void aNewMethod()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate {
            if (progress.Value == 0)
            {
                //Heavy work
                for (int i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) { }
                progress.Value = 100;
            }
        });
     }
```

This solved the `System.InvalidOperationException` but it's not running asynchronously as the UI still freezes at `for loop`

So the question is : How to run the `aNewMethod();` asynchronously and still update and interact with UI controls ?

Comment: use `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`

Comment: Sakura: I think this is virtually the same as Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412670/whats-the-difference-between-invokeasync-and-begininvoke-for-wpf-dispatcher

Comment: you are trying to access UI thread object in another thread which is not allwoed

Comment: You are explicitly asking `Sleep` to run on UI thread. Not sure what else you'd expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dispatcher runs in the UI thread. It handles your UI, and executes actions you pass to it via BeginInvoke etc.
But it can only handle one thing at a time; when it's busy handling your action, it won't update the UI in the meantime, so the UI freezes in the meantime.

If you want to keep your UI responsive, you'd need to run the heavy load functions in a seperate, non-UI thread. Within those functions running on another thread, you can call the dispatcher whenever you need access to the UI - ideally, only very briefly for the purpose of updating UI elements.

So in other words, you'd want to be running your sleep function in a seperate thread, and then just make a call to the Dispatcher from your own thread when you need to set the progress value. Something like

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() => aNewMethod());  // will call aNewMethod on the thread pool
}

private void aNewMethod()
{
    double progressValue = 0;
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progressValue = progress.Value);

    if (progressValue == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000); // still executes on the threadpool (see above), so not blocking UI
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => progress.Value = 100 );  // call the dispatcher to access UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: your sample is somewhat misleading - either use `async` all the way through and you don't need `BeginInvoke` at all OR use threads and manually call back to UI thread with `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Fair enough - you may want to use BeginInvoke if continuing work on the worker thread afterwards that doesn't need to wait for the UI to update.. but I've amended this example to a synchronous call to the dispatcher, might be clearer.

Comment: purpose of ``async`` and ``await`` is to eliminate this ``Dispatcher.Invoke``, so if we use these with ``async`` and ``await``, then it does not makes sense

Answer (score 2):

With you current implementation, there is no need to use `Thread.Start`, as in that method you are just sleeping it for some time and accessing UI thread objects there which is not allowed
.In your scenario a better way of doing is that you should not use `Thread.Sleep` instead of that you should be doing it with [`Task.Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        if (progress.Value == 0)
        {
             await Task.Delay(3000); 
             progress.Value = 100;
        } 


}
```

Now you don't need `Dispatcher.Invoke`, and credit goes to `async` and `await` keywords as statements after await will be executing in the same calling synchronization context from where we did async call which is UI thread in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> onClick a button, a aNewMethod() would run asynchronously to keep UI responsive.

Actually, it's running *synchronously* on a *background thread*. `Task.Run` is perfectly appropriate for this.

> after some Googling, I've read that I need a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method to update/use UI controls

Unfortunately, this is one area where Google will certainly mislead you. `Dispatcher` is *not* the best solution here.

Instead, you should use `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>`, as such:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var progress = new Progress<int>(value => { this.progress.Value = value; });
  await Task.Run(() => aNewMethod(progress));
}

private void aNewMethod(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  //Heavy work
  for (int i = 1; i < 1000000000; i++) { }
  progress.Report(100);
}
```