# Dispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeAsync' and no extension method 'InvokeAsync'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, dispatcher

Please I'm having error and this is my code.

```
private void ComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _comboBox.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ContentChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty));
        }
```

its saying  `Dispatcher' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeAsync' and no extension method 'InvokeAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'Dispatcher' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? wpf`  I'm lost please, i need help on these. Thanks.

Comment: Write it as ``_comboBox.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync((Action)(() => ContentChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty)));``

Comment: @RandRandom Same issue Sir...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` is definitely an existing method **as of .NET 4.5**. You'll see that error if you try to compile for .NET 4.0 or earlier.

It has the same effect as if you had called `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. The difference is `BeginInvoke` accepts a delegate(requiring a cast from a lambda), whereas `InvokeAsync` doesn't, because it accepts an `Action`. This was done to refactor the API, but in a manner that didn't break code still using `BeginInvoke`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412670/whats-the-difference-between-invokeasync-and-begininvoke-for-wpf-dispatcher) for more details.

**Before .NET 4.5**:

```
_comboBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
    ContentChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
}));
```

**Since .NET 4.5**:

```
_comboBox.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {
    ContentChanged?.Invoke(sender, EventArgs.Empty);
});
```