# MoveFocus won't trigger on TabItem Header click event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabcontrol

`DataGrid` is located on `Tab1`. If I am located on `Tab2` and I click on the `Tab1` header the program switches to `Tab1` and the `DataGrid` scrolls into view at the right position, but the selected `Row` won't get focused(highlighted) unless I click on the `Tab1` header again. The rest of the code is triggering just fine.

CS

```
private void Tab1_Clicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (dg_address.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        dg_address.ScrollIntoView(dg_address.Items[dg_address.SelectedIndex]);
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg_address.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg_address.SelectedIndex);
        row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TabControl x:Name="tab_control"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Background="#FFE5E5E5">

    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Seznam"
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="Tab1_Clicked"/>
        </TabItem.Header>
```

Comment: Try to use `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ... )` to execute your code to set focus with various priorities (often you need `Render` to ensure what WPF finish everything required to render). That's a "first step" solution in cases like this due to somewhat deferred (queued) nature of wpf.

Comment: @Sinatr Would you care to explain the difference between Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => ... ) and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => ... ), I'm a complete newbie when it comes to C# and those two methods produce the same result.

Comment: @Sinatr Found the answer myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412670/whats-the-difference-between-invokeasync-and-begininvoke-for-wpf-dispatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3baa240a-c687-449e-af77-989ff4d78333/how-to-move-focus-to-a-textbox-in-a-tabcontrol-on-a-button-click?forum=wpf

```
private void Tab1_Clicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (dg_address.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        dg_address.ScrollIntoView(dg_address.Items[dg_address.SelectedIndex]);
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg_address.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg_address.SelectedIndex);
            row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
        );
    }
}
```

or

```
private void Tab1_Clicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (dg_address.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        dg_address.ScrollIntoView(dg_address.Items[dg_address.SelectedIndex]);
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg_address.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(dg_address.SelectedIndex);
            row.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }
        ));
    }
}
```

Edit: Optimized and removed a bug in the code.