# Serial Port Communication WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am doing a Desktop Application on WPF MVVM.

I am trying to communicate via Serial Port, the data has been successfully retrieved using the SerialDataReceivedEventArgs
and however when I want to automatically execute a function it giving me an exception of:

I try to Debug it and the code successfully go through the function, it immediately break and end the debug mode (end the application).

> System.ArgumentException: 'Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.'

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
      {

         try
         {
            dataRetreived = devicesSerialPort.ReadLine();
            dataRetreived = dataRetreived.Replace("\r", "");
            CurrentDatas = dataRetreived;
            AnalyzeCurrentData();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
      }
```

How to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Jazb, Serial Port does not have method to Freeze.

Comment: You can use [Dispatcher.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke) to switch to the UI thread

Comment: @KlausGütter does `Dispatcher.Invoke` suffer from the same thread-deadlock risks that WinForm's `Control.Invoke` does?  Perhaps `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` would be better?

Comment: Nowadays [Dispatcher.InvokeAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13412670/1136211).